# Did the spear of the Night King reach its target?

Tags: game-of-thrones

In *Game of Thrones* S08E03 the Night King threw a spear at Daenerys after she unsuccessfully tried Dragon Fire on him.

When the spear heads towards Daenerys, we can hear a reaction sound from her, but later she was shown unhurt and the spear was never shown.

Even the Night King smirked after the reaction sound. Is it a director's error or something suspicious to look in next episodes?

Comment: The sound was her effort to lunge from the attack

Answer (score 9):

If you watch it again you will see the spear passing a meter or 2 above her right shoulder and missing completely.